# Conformal generators in spinor-helicity variables

Tags: conformal-field-theory, spinors, ads-cft, helicity

The question in particular pertains to Section D.1 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.04234. In this section, they have written the conformal generators of 3d in terms of the spinor-helicity variables. Unfortunately, these generators seem to be useful for conserved currents and scalars of conformal dimension 2. How does one generalize these generators to arbitrary conformal dimensions?

Comment: A question to clarify something: are you asking for a generalization of eq.(D.1) or the action of the said operator to fields of arbitrary conformal dimension?

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 The latter,